# JavaScript `replace` syntax

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm very new to JavaScript and came across an exercise solution that I want to fully understand.

The exercise asked to remove all vowels from a string. The solution:

```
function disemvowel(str) {
  return str.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, '');
}
```

I understand the basic syntax:

- whatever is between the /'s is what you want replaced
- second parameter is what to replace it with
- /g is a 'global tag'....? so not just the first instance

My questions:

- What do the brackets in the solution represent?
- What is the i after /g? I read that it means ignore, but what is it ignoring?

Thank you for any info!! :)

Comment: i is for ignoring "case" of string , whether they r uppercase or lowercase

Comment: Read documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: The `i` is a flag (like the `g`) for `ignorecase`, so the regular expression matches both upper and lower case. The brackets indicate a grouping, matching any character contained within.

Comment: Have you read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)?

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is what's called a "regular expression". In JavaScript, you have what are called "regular expression literals", which is the `/[aeiou]/gi` thing. The `[aeiou]` is known as a "character class" or a "character set", which means "match one of `aeiou`". The `g` and `i` after the closing `/` are flags that determine how the regular expression behaves. `g` means "global" or "find all matches", and `i` means "case insensitive". You then replace all these matches with an empty string `''` so that all the occurrences of vowels are removed in the generated string

Comment: Regex101 is a nice site to test these. On the side it shows an explanation. https://regex101.com/r/mw9Gj3/2

Answer (score 0):

You type inside the brackets all characters to match (think of it as a enum of characters). `i` is for case **I**nsensitive.

Answer (score 0):

`/[aeiou]/gi` will match a any of the characters `a,e,i,o,u` with `case insensitivity` which is what the `i` at the end is for

Basically in your case it will remove all occurences of vowels from your string (replace vowels with empty string)

```js
const str = "hUnger gamEs";

console.log(str.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])